# Div don't want to scroll to bottom

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I created a horizontal drop-down full-screen menu maked it scroll able,when there is overflow(drop down is toggled).But unfortunately i got a big problem.(This menu is for tablets.)The problem is there when you go on tablet and open the menu it always cut bottom half of the last li element.I created a new div inside overlay one in which i will put my other menu,here is picture of what i mean [This](http://prntscr.com/de6854) If you go on tablet and toggle it,it will cut the bottom of the last Li element and all of the new div.Here is my CSS and HTML:

```css
/******************************************
             Tablet Menu Style
*******************************************/
.tablet-menu{
display:none;
background:#000;
position:fixed;
height:100%;
width:100%;
opacity:0.7;
z-index:1001;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.tablet-menu.show{
display:block;
}
.tablet-menu-scroll{
overflow:scroll;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="tablet-menu">
   <ul class="tablet-menu-scroll">
<!-- php code for calling menu-->
     <div class="overlay-lang-menu"></div>
            </ul>
           </div>
```

I think that is all of code you guys need(i don't wanna paste all of it to waste more of your time0 If there anything you need to know more,please ask.

Comment: Have you tried to set overflow-x: scroll instead of overflow: scroll? That may resolve your problem.

Comment: yep,but i want it to be scrollable (horizontal) when you set overflow-x it wont even scroll,it will scroll only with `oveflow:scroll;` or `overflow-y:scroll;`

Comment: overflow-x: scroll; is for horizontal scroll only and it should work.

Comment: Lol sorry i meant vertcal,it was a looong day yesterday :D

Comment: Please post more code or make a fiddle.